# Чек сумма, что значит взять по модулю

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть условие задачи:

> Нам дан массив для которого нужно посчитать контрольную сумму. Делается это следующим образом: каждый элемент (начиная с первого) добавляем к текущему результату и умножаем то что получилось на 113 - то что получилось берем по модулю 10000007 - оно и будет новым значением результата, и так далее.

Всё понял, всё написал. Но вот как это взять по модулю? не пойму. Подскажите. Это делить по модулю или другая операция. Спасибо.

код

```
public class ArrayChecksum {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Введите данные: ");
    String scan = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    String[] StArr = scan.split(" ");

    int sum =0;

    for(String i: StArr){
        sum += Integer.valueOf(i);
        System.out.println(sum);
        //sum *= 113;
    }//for

    sum *= 113;
    System.out.println(sum);
    int asum = sum % 10000007;

    System.out.println(asum + " ");
  }// main
}// ArrayChecksum'''
```

Comment: делить по модулю, скорее всего

Comment: Пробовал. Но возвращает сумму как и без деления(((

Comment: `Но возвращает сумму как и без деления(((` - если sum меньше 10000007, то sum % 10000007 будет равно sum. Так и должно быть.

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Решил)) нужно было просто все указанные действия делать с каждым числом.

Comment: Если комуто  интересно то это 17 задача на CodeAbbey

Answer (score 0):

Да, речь о делении по модулю. Но ты его используешь не там, где надо, поэтому результат неверный.